# Jetty Http Client logging

Tags: java, jetty, httpclient

I am using Jetty Http Client v7.5.4. 
The problem is that all Warn messages are coming on the console. I understand that Jetty uses sl4j. Since my app uses log4j, I have placed **slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar** and **slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar** in the classpath.

Is there anything else I need to do so that I can capture the logs in a file?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should [redirect jetty sysout](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/StdErrStdOut).

Comment: That example is for Jetty Server. I am looking to configure for Jetty Http Client

Comment: Oh, so you refer to Jetty's HttpClient class?

Comment: The link is dead. I guess that's why you should always summarize what the link is about.